# passing value from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

is there a work around on how I can pass the value from 'value' going to an if statement?

I get the value now showing 1 or 0. What im trying to accomplish now is how I can pass it in the if statement. I wanted to have something like this. If val = 0 return true; else return false. Im not sure I'm in the right track of using the ajax function. But if there a better way you can show me I will appreciate it.

```
$(function(){ 
       $('#add_product').click(function(){ 
         var i = $('#product_name').val(); 
         param = 'product_name='+i; 
         check_product(param).done(function(value) {
        var val = value; //value return is 1 or 0 - this is fine
         });
         //val should be past here so that I can determine if I will return true or false
         if(val == 0){
            return true;
         } else{
            return false;
         }
       }); 
    });

function check_product(param){ 
  return $.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST', 
    data : param, 
    url : baseurl+'cart/check_product_name/'
 });
}
```

html form:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('cart/save_product'); ?>
<h3>Product Name:</h3>
<?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'product_name', 'id' => 'product_name'), set_value('product_name')); ?>
<h3>Price:</h3>
<?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'price', 'id' => 'price'), set_value('price')); ?>
<h3>Status:</h3>
<?php
$options = array(
    '1' => 'Active',
    '0' => 'Not Active'
);
echo form_dropdown('status', $options);
 ?>
<h3>Short Description:</h3>
<?php echo form_textarea(array('name' => 'short_description', 'id' => 'short_desc'), set_value('short_description')); ?>
<h3>Image:</h3>
<?php echo form_upload('userfile'); ?><br>
<p class="submit" id="post_submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="add_product" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is `#add_product`, and why do you need to prevent/not prevent the click based on the returned value. Is it an anchor element that links to another page, if so include the HTML of that element in your question.

Comment: #add_product comes from here: <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="add_product" /> a submit form. I edited the question and added the html form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to prevent the form from submitting, and then check with ajax if the product name exists, and when the ajax call has completed do the form submit with javascript if the returned value is zero:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add_product').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var i     = $('#product_name').val(),
            param = 'product_name=' + i,
            self  = this;
        check_product(param).done(function(value) {
            if (value === 0) self.submit();
        });
    });
});

function check_product(param) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: param,
        url: baseurl + 'cart/check_product_name/'
    });
}​
```

Comment: @IliaG - could you please ellaborate a little on that, as now the if/else statement is inside the success callback where there is an actual value to check, and in the OP's code it's outside the success callback, and since ajax is asynchronous that surely won't work.

Comment: it still has the same issue scope. Your `return`ing inside anonymous function that will execute after click event has already completed.

Comment: Yes, but that's unavoidable when returning from an asyncronous function, and the only (poor) solution would be synchronous calls, locking the browser.

Comment: Which is a valid answer... as opposed to your solution that substitutes one scope issue for another.

Comment: @IliaG - I did in fact add it to my answer, but using async:false is such a poor solution that I don't think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: hi guys, sorry but the above code is still not working on my end. Is there a better way of doing this?

basically I only want to check from the server using ajax. if the product name exist or not. if it exist alert user(return false) else (return true) save the data in the database.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to alert the user inside the done() function when the ajax call has completed, and storing the values in the DB can be done at the same time you're checking if the product name exists or not.

Comment: I understand this is the first thing I did and should actually be done. But im having an issue with the textarea(tiny_mce) at first time the user input some text. the value is not pass but when clicking refresh or submitting it again, thats the time the value in the textarea is being pass which is not right.

that is why I came up with this idea to just check the name only and if its not existing in the database I redirect it to another URL for saving the data.

Comment: You'll need to prevent the default action of clicking the link, and then do the redirect when the ajax call is completed, like my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @adeneo I finally got what I wanted! :)